# Loading JQuery into Joomla 3 for date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, joomla3.0

I've been having some trouble lately getting the JQuery datepicker function to work in a custom Joomla module. I use Jumi to integrate a PHP file into the website that displays a datepicker application in the frontend. If I'm using it correctly according to the JQuery website I have to call for the following files:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Doing it like this works fine, the date pickers does the job and can be used. However, since Joomla comes with its own JQuery library (media/jui/js) I'm wondering how to use the files in this folder instead. At the same time this might avoid certain JQuery conflicts as well. For example I'm having a slider module displayed on the same page and it basically goes ballistic when both are displayed (datepicker + slider). When I disable the call for Jquery-1.9.1 in my application the slider works but the datepicker functionality disappears. I've also tried the following by calling the Joomla Jquery framework:

```
<?php
// load jQuery scripts
// loaded from Joomla! 3
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
// loaded from the code.jquery.com site
$doc->addStylesheet('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
?>
```

However, this also prevents the datepicker from working correctly. It looks like the datepicker functionality is not supported in this way. Basically my question comes down to how I can have both the slider and the datepicker application to work in the best way possible without having conflicts.

Other solutions used:
- Adding noConflict
- Using Easy JQuery

Help is highly appreciated since I'm getting bald pulling my hair out...

Comment: Hey, can you check out date picker class in Joomla? Its what I am doing now, as I have the same issue

Comment: Hey Daydah, could you be more specific? I have solved the issue with some rework on the template and now I have both slider and application working alongside. Not the prettiest solution but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Sure I can be more specific.

I use *DirectPHP* for my own custom *PHP* coding within *Joomla!*. Like you, I needed a datepicker in my code. While searching for a *PHP* datepicker (I knew from experience that anything totally JQuery is bound to trigger issues) I came across tutorials on how to use Joomla!'s own built-in datepicker. You can find the one that worked for me [here](http://bitmapcake.blogspot.com/2014/01/joomla-datepicker.html).

Their only complaint was styling, which I believe can be overcome via *CSS*. My upgrade was to use `date()` function to input the current date into their solution.

Problem solved!

Comment: I have a go with this solution. Have you used in Joomla 3?

Comment: Yes I have used it in Joomla 3. See my test site [here](http://www.daydah.net/eben/index.php/add-new-pen.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have also had jQuery conflicts when using two modules on the same page. jQuery Easy can be your friend, but understanding how to do it manually is probably more useful. Also, be sure to use jQuery.noconflict() so the jQuery "$" doesn't conflict with Mootools "$".

**But, I have successfully used Date picker on Joomla 3.**

Joomla 3.0 - 3.??? has had some jQuery and Mootools conflicts. Also, in some of the early versions there was a tooltips bug that prevented date picker from working correctly. I've been using the jQuery date picker for one of my modules since Joomla 3.0, but I believe I had to change a couple things when I upgraded to Joomla 3.3.1 .

**The following lines in my template index.php file gave me the libraries necessary to successfully use jQuery date picker in Joomla 3.3.1 :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

jQuery 1.8 and 1.10 seem to work. Also I don't think it matters whether or not you load the jQuery framework files below:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
```